# Равномерное распределение ширины колонок

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

У меня есть листинг производителей, и мне необходимо, чтобы отсчет был не слева направо, а сверху вниз, и высота у родительского блока была фиксирована.

```
<div class="col-12 car-list2-col">
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">КамАЗ <span>152</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">МаЗ <span>289</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Полуприцеп <span>398</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
                <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
            </div>
```

Вот стили родителя:

```
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
max-height: 135px;
justify-content: flex-start;
```

у item'a стилей нет.
Все встало нормально, но флекс все колонки распределил равномерно по всей ширине родителя.выглядит это так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо что бы колонки не распределялись равномерно по всей ширине а прибивались в лево. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: Напишите часть Вашего кода в специальный редактор кода. В редакторе поста есть сверху панелька. найдите иконку листа А4 с сиволами `< >` и вставьте туда код) link на стили указывать не надо)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.car-list2-col {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 135px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.car-list2-col>div {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 car-list2-col">
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">КамАЗ <span>152</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">МаЗ <span>289</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Полуприцеп <span>398</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
  <div class="car-list2_item"><a href="#">Краз <span>258</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обернуть ваш код в `<div style="display: inline-block;">`, а классу "car-list2_item" добавить необходимые отступы